# How to loop through a range of cells when only the column is known using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task to return all the consecutive rows in a particular column.  They will all have data consecutively and the first blank row will signal the end of the data.  I used this to find the column and pass that over to my range, but I keep getting syntax errors.

```
Dim Col
Dim found As Boolean
Dim cellRange As Range

    found = Cells.Find(What:="My_Search_Text", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    'Take that column as the range.
    If (found) Then
        Col = ActiveCell.Column
        cellRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Col, ActiveSheet.Range(Col).End(xlDown)).Select
```

The goal here is to get the correct range of cells and loop through them, however, I'm not at the loop part as the last line is the one that doesn't work at all.

So what is the correct syntax for this last line and is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Column` returns the column number, not the column as a range.

Comment: That is what I thought I needed to get the range, find the column first.

Comment: `Find()` returns a range, so your `found` declaration should be "As Range". And remove the ".Activate" from the end of Find(). Then use `Col = found.Column`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following which I have tested with a selection of situations.

I have included notes about the changes I have made but come back with questions if anything is unclear.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindRange()

  Dim RangeStart As Range
  Dim RangeEndPlusOne As Range
  Dim RangeEntire As Range

  ' Better to explicitly identify the sheet being searched
  With Sheets("Source")
    ' Do not attempt to activate the target cell.  Instead get it as a range.
    ' Are you sure about "LookAt:=xlPart"?  "LookAt:=xlWhole" might be better
    ' I have explicitly started the search from cell A1 rather than the current
    ' position of the cursor.
    Set RangeStart = .Cells.Find(What:="My_Search_Text", After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If RangeStart Is Nothing Then
      ' My "My_Search_Text" not found
    Else
      ' If the cell below RangeStart is empty, End(xlDown) will jump to
      ' the bottom of the column or the next cell in the column with a value.
      ' Search down the column for an empty cell
      Set RangeEndPlusOne = .Columns(RangeStart.Column).Find(What:="", _
                             After:=RangeStart, _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                             MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      ' I ought to test for not found but I assume there is a blank cell below
      ' RangeStart

      Set RangeEntire = .Range(RangeStart, RangeEndPlusOne.Offset(-1, 0))

      Debug.Print "Start  " & RangeStart.Address
      Debug.Print "End+1  " & RangeEndPlusOne.Address
      Debug.Print "Entire " & RangeEntire.Address
    End If

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one. You've taken time to give a full answer. Note that you could use the `If Not` to avoid an `If 'nothing to do Else` :)

Comment: You are right but my brain hurts with boolean expressions like `Not X Is Nothing`; I prefer to have a empty `Then` block.  However: (1) in the real code I would expect some action if the target text is not found and (2) it is good that you point this out to James who may not have my mental limitations.

Comment: I have VBA limitations as I'm a Java dev that has been out of Excel VBA code for 12 years.  Thank you for the excellent answer and your patience.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using objects in VBA, you need to use the keyword `Set` when assigning a variable, your first statement should be:

```
Set found = Cells.Find(What:="My_Search_Text", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

By the way, you cannot assign **and** use a method as `Activate`. So I removed it at the end of the statement.

Comment: This isn't working either.  I'm just using the find to get the column number so I can then get a range.  How do I define a variable for this?

Comment: @JamesDrinkard: have a look at Tony's answer. He is giving you a whole working solution

Answer (score 2):

How about this to get your last row?

```
LastRow = SheetToCheck.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlDown).Row
```

This will return the last row before the break/blank cell.

Then set your range using:

```
Set cellRange = SheetToCheck.Range(SheetToCheck.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column), SheetToCheck.Cells(LastRow, ActiveCell.Column))
```

Comment: BTW, I dislike using ActiveCell/ActiveSheet/Selection as they can cause issues if you lose your way. I find it's better to refer to the cell/sheet directly. If using a currently selected cell, then assign it with Set myCell = ActiveCell, that way if the selection changes mid-process, you won't get gummed up.